# How to know when Activity is finished in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android app I want to change the input method. So I start a new `Activity` which shows the language settings in the device. Then user can change it. However then I want to know that if the user has changed it. So I wrote a function for that also. My code so far is...

```
Intent enableIME = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(enableIME,0);


                    if(isInputMethodEnabled()){
                        activateshadow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed));
                        activateshadow.setText("Deactivate Shadow");
                        prefs.edit().putBoolean("Activate", false).commit();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You haven't change the input method to simpleIME.In order to activate you must change it.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

my is inputMethodEnabled function is....

```
  public boolean isInputMethodEnabled() {
  boolean isIME ;  
  String id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
    String [] name = id.split("/.");
   // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"s:"+name[1]+":s",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(name[1].contains("SimpleIME") ){
        isIME = true ;
    }else{
        isIME = false;
    }
   //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Returning..."+isIME,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return isIME;
}
```

`if(isInputMethodEnabled())` always fails because when the `new intent(settings)` opens and it take some time to change the input method to `simpleIME` . How to fix this problem?

Comment: Your question title is straightforward, the body is not. Please start a second question to avoid confusion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You catch when a launched `Activity` returns in `onActivityResult`. The `requestCode` you supplied to `startActivityForResult` will be a parameter, as will the `Activity`'s result. The `Activity` may also set other data which you didn't ask about.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 555) {//555 is the intent ID you gave in startActivityForResult(enableIME,555);
        if (resultCode == /*Result1*/)
            //Do something
        else {
            //Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

You need a unique id when calling `startActivityForResult(enableIME,0);`

```
startActivityForResult(enableIME, 555);
```

Better still replace 555 with a named variable.

Comment: Thanks. but what is the resultCode here, I am not returning anything from my second activity. Actually I am just enable my IME and then return to the my app main activity by pressing back button.

Comment: Don't worry about that. You can detect when the `Activity` finished in `onActivityResult`

Comment: ok. so how should I use this method in my code. what are the argument values i should pass.? for requestCode i doesn't matter.I got it.What about other 2 arguments?

Comment: Thanks John.I'll try this one

Answer (score 0):

if u look at android life cycle, when activity is finished whole android call onDestroy() method.
so u can call and override this method.
just need write:

```
@override
protected void onDestroy(){
// code
super.onDestroy();
}
```

u can manage and override all of life cycle's parts in android
e.g: onResume to get current activity

i hope this help u

Comment: `onDestroy` isn't always called, for example if the `Activity` is kicked out of the recents list.